# Pause a for loop to await user interaction

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, user-interaction

I'm having a bit of a problem figuring out how to pause a for...next loop to await user interaction. I'm comparing the hashes of different files in a for...next loop and if they are different, I want to pause the loop until the user decided which file to keep.

Here's my code, so i hope you see what I'm trying to do.

```
 For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If GetCRC32(ListBox1.Items.Item(i)) = GetCRC32(ListBox2.Items.Item(i)) Then
            log("same")
        Else

            Dim v1 As String = ListBox1.Items.Item(i)
            Dim v2 As String = ListBox2.Items.Item(i)
            Dim f1 As New FileInfo(v1)
            Dim f2 As New FileInfo(v2)
            Dim c As String
            If f1.LastWriteTime > f2.LastWriteTime Then
                c = v1
            Else
                c = v2
            End If
            RichTextBox1.Text = v1 & " and " & v2 & " seem to be different." & vbCrLf & _
                "Last changed:" & c
        End If
    Next
```

The user-interaction is via two buttons, which I have no code for yet...

Comment: No need to pause the loop explicitly, just put the user interaction in directly.

Comment: sounds like you want to interrupt your loop with a messagebox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I also thought this through, might be the best solution. Thank you guys!

Comment: use environment.newline.. not vbCrLf. Also, you should consider doing a multithreaded application for this purpose/behavior/condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use Form.ShowDialog in the loop.
Stops execution of the loop and you can ask user whatever question you need.